# How to switch characters in a string two characters at a time

Tags: c

I am working on my first attempt at learning C. I want to know if it is possible to change the characters of a string by two. Meaning if I have a word: "Hello", how do I set up a function that will change the string to: "hlelo". Currently I have a method called

```
void word_reverse(char* str)
{
    strrev(str);//changes the whole string in reverse
}
```

How do I make it to change two characters in a string at a time? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It can be done, but it's hard not to wonder why you would want to do that? That just gets so messy so fast (for example, what happens if the string has an odd number of characters. Also when you say two characters at a time, do you mean the string really is reversed, or just kinda reversed [in blocks of two]?)

Comment: Cause our professor is the anti-christ lol

Comment: What do you mean by change the characters of a string by 2? You aren't reversing words. You are just switching two character. Try rewording the question so we can see what you are trying to do. And asking homework questions because you don't want to open the textbook is really no a good idea. Not only are you wasting our time but you will never learn anything if you don't try. How do you think we all learned? Well. I never used a textbook because I didn't go to school but google is the modern day textbook right?

Comment: @ManuelMangual Ah yes, Psalm 127:1 "And the darkness descended and wished for the reversing of strings, but in unholy pairings".

Comment: Can you explain how you get to 'hlelo' if you move two characters at once? I'm having a hard time visualizing what they want you do to.

Comment: You can't expect SO to just do your homework for you. Even if you're starting to learn C, your professor would've set the difficulty to a reasonable level. Go back to your lecture notes or do some googling yourself. Come back when you have some code you've written and is stuck on. For starters, I'd suggest look into arrays and for loops and how to manipulate for loop's iterating in different orders.

Comment: I wonder if they don't mean an algorithm that works from the outside inward. Sort of like "Hello" after the first step becomes "oellH" and after the second step is "olleH"? If so, put at pointer at the beginning, put a pointer at the end, then slide both inwards until the pointers are equal.

Comment: I reworded the title. And I don't expect the site to hand me the answers cause even I would not stand for it. I just need a heading on how to get started.

Comment: @sircodesalot that is correct

Comment: @ManuelMangual in that case a good starter is http://www.amazon.com/Starting-Out-Early-Objects-Edition/dp/013336092X/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1394498858&sr=8-3&keywords=tony+gaddis+c%2B%2B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not working this out in front of a compiler so you'll have to do the work to make this actually run, but this should get you started at least.

```
char *resersi(char *string) {
  char *start = string;
  char *end = string;

  // move the end pointer to the end (c-style strings end in '\0')
  while (*end != 0) end ++;

  // move the end pointer back one away from the end (we don't want to swap '\0')
  end--;

  // Slide the start pointer and end pointer inwards until they overlap or cross.
  while (start < end) {
     // Swap the values
     char temp = *end;
     *end = *start;
     *start = temp; 

     // Slide the pointers
     start++;
     end--;
  }

  return string;
}
```

Here is a basic outline of what you'll need to do.

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate that is not the complete answer, but it is a basic idea that helped me figure out what I needed to do. Now it works fine! Thank you again and to all that also commented.